# How to pass MenuItem in Bundle to Dialog Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

I need to pass `MenuItem generateProgress = menu.findItem(R.id.generate_movie);` to `newInstance` of my DialogFragment, and in this instance pass it with a `Bundle` to `onCreateDialog`.

```
public void showGifDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = GenerateGifDialogFragment.newInstance(generateProgress);
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "generateGif");
}
```

and

```
public static GenerateGifDialogFragment newInstance(MenuItem generateProgress) {
    GenerateGifDialogFragment f = new GenerateGifDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    // pass here MenuItem
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}
```

How I can pass build-in Android interface? Should I create a class and extend it? Or is it better way, like calling directly to menu from `getActivity()` and findingItem from Fragment class?

Comment: Why do you want to pass a **copy** of MenuItem to another class/fragment at all?

Comment: I want to call `generateProgress.setActionView(R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);` so it shows the loading icon on the position of actual icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a similar thing, by creating a method in my activity and then accessing it through `getActivity()`. Here's an example:

```
private boolean mProgressShown;
private MenuItem mSearchItem;
private SearchView mSearchView;
private View mProgressView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Prepare progress layout for usage later
    mProgressView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.progress_icon, null);
    ...
}

public void showProgressIcon() {
    if (mSearchItem != null && !mProgressShown) {
        mProgressShown = true;
        mSearchItem.setActionView(mProgressView);
    }
}

public void hideProgressIcon() {
    if (mSearchItem != null && mProgressShown) {
        mProgressShown = false;
        mSearchItem.setActionView(mSearchView);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    mSearchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) mSearchItem.getActionView();
    ...
}
```

Then from my fragments I would call:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity).showProgressIcon();
((MainActivity)getActivity).hideProgressIcon();
```